# How do I make a simple loading screen with just characters?

Tags: c++, loading

I'm trying to make a loading screen for a simulation I have to do, so the console isn't just blank for 10 seconds. I just want to add an asterisk to a line every 2 seconds of simulation time. Here's the code for I came up with for the loading screen.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
int main()
{
    //initialize a random seed
    srand(time(NULL));
    time_t simTime=10;
    time_t passedTime=0;
    time_t beginTime=time(NULL);
    do
    {
        time_t currentTime=time(NULL);
        passedTime=currentTime-beginTime;
        //Code for simulation
        if(passedTime%2==0)
            cout<<"*";
        cout<<endl;
    }while(passedTime<simTime);
```

It just prints out asterisks neverendingly for 10 seconds.

Comment: Currently your code is going to print so many asterisks for each multiple of 2. You should somehow store which multiply is used and avoid print duplicate asterisk, or use a different wait approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't necessarily need a separate thread if you simply want to print out the asterisks while you do your similation in your loop.
Here's an example based on your code:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    float simulation_duration = 0.0;
    float maximum_duration = 10.0;
    auto time_since_start_or_last_asterisk = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    do {

        //Code for simulation
        auto current_time = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::chrono::duration<double> time_since_last_asterisk = current_time - time_since_start_or_last_asterisk;
        if (time_since_last_asterisk.count() >= 2.0){
            cout << "*";
            cout.flush();
            simulation_duration += time_since_last_asterisk.count();
            time_since_start_or_last_asterisk = current_time;
        }

    } while (simulation_duration < maximum_duration);
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: I think my school's compiler maybe on c++98 or something because I can't use the chrono header

Comment: Well, do you mind accepting one of the answers and upvoting both answers then? The thread answer is pretty good too.

Answer (score 2):

You implemented active waiting. You will need two threads: One that does the loading and one that mostly sleeps and prints the asterisc every two seconds or so. Maybe something like this:

```
bool loadingComplete;

void PrintLoading()
{
    do
    {
        std::cout << '*';
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(2s);
    }
    while(!loadingComplete);
}

void LoadStuff()
{
    // Long running task
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t(PrintLoading);

    loadingComplete = false;
    LoadStuff();
    loadingComplete = true;

    t.join();
}
```

Without actively interrupting the thread this might run 2 seconds longer than needed and I didn't have time to test, but I hope it points you in the right direction.